# Scala map Future[IOResult] to Future[Unit]

Tags: scala

I have a function that must return a Future[Unit].

In my function I'm writing a file which returns a Future[IOResult]. Both the Future and the IOResult can have a failure status.

I'd like to check for success and failure of both the Future and the IOResult in my function, but just return a Failure[Unit] from this function, is this possible?

The code below is reporting errors:

```
discarded non-Unit value
[error]           Future.successful(Unit)

discarded non-Unit value
[error]           Future.failed(e)
```

Here is my function:

```
def create(filePath: String, fileStream: Source[ByteString, Any]): Future[Unit] = {

    val writeResultFuture: Future[IOResult] = fileStream.runWith(FileIO.toPath(filePath))

    writeResultFuture map { writeResult =>
      writeResult.status match {
        case Success(_) =>
          logger.info(s"Successfully uploaded: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath")
          Future.successful(Unit)
        case Failure(e) =>
          logger.error(s"Failed to upload: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath", e)
          Future.failed(e)
      }
    } recover {
      case e =>
        logger.error(s"Failed to upload: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath", e)
        Future.failed(e)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things.

1. `Unit` is not a value of type `Unit` (it's a reference to an `object scala.Unit` defined in scala library). You want `()` to denote a value of `Unit`.
2. The function you give to `recover` is supposed to return the actual result, not a `Future` (`recoverWith` works with futures).
3. The function you give to `map` returns the actual result too. You'd want `flatMap` if you actually needed to return a `Future`

So, something like this should work:

```
writeResultFuture.map { writeResult =>
    writeResult.status match {
        case Success(_) =>
          logger.info(s"Successfully uploaded: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath")
        case Failure(e) =>
          logger.error(s"Failed to upload: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath", e)
          throw e
    }
  }.recover { case e =>
        logger.error(s"Failed to upload: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath", e)
        throw e
  }
```

Better yet, use `onFailure` instead of `recover` - that way you don't need to rethrow. Just do `.onFailure { e => logger.error(...) }`
Also, note that you are logging errors twice this way (once inside `map`, and then again in `recover`/`onFailure`) ... Consider removing the `recover` part alltogether.

```
  writeResultFuture.map(_.status).map { 
    case Success(_) => logger.info(s"Successfully uploaded: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath")
    case Failure(e) => logger.error(s"Failed to upload: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath", e)
        throw e
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
  writeResultFuture flatMap { writeResult =>
    writeResult.status match {
      case Success(_) =>
        logger.info(s"Successfully uploaded: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath")
        Future.successful()
      case Failure(e) =>
        Future.failed(e)
    }
  } recover {
    case e =>
      logger.error(s"Failed to upload: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath", e)
  }
```

Using `flatMap` will flatten the nested `Future` returned by your `match` statement, and `recover` now returns `Unit` so that result is `Future[Unit]`. `recover` will catch all errors that are generated so you don't need to print anything in the inner `Failure` case.

Comment: Tim you can add the unit () inside the Future.successful(())
easy to forget. But I agree this should work

Answer (score 0):

You are returning Future's so your end result will be of type Future[Future[…]], in your case we do not need to nest at all, so we can change the code to:

DISCLAIMER: I only typed the code in here, it has not been typechecked, YMMV. No warranties. etc etc

```
fileStream.runWith(FileIO.toPath(filePath)) transform {
  case Failure(e) => Failure(e)
  case Success(i: IOResult) => i.status
} andThen {
    case Success(_) =>
      logger.info(s"Successfully uploaded: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath")
    case Failure(e) =>
      logger.error(s"Failed to upload: ${fileInfo.fileName} to: $filePath", e)
  }
} map { _ => () }
```